# View GIT history of current open file in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

I always open a file and then right click => Git => Show History to see git history of a file. I'm a bit lazy to do that all times.

Is there any hotkeys or way to add combine keys to show git history of current open file on Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the keyboard shortcut key for show git history option. For that you need to go to File-> Setting option and in the keymap section under version control system you can add your preferred keyboard shortcut

[image]